# Can pd.DataFrame.set_index mantain dtype?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to call `df.set_index` in such a way that the `dtype` of the column I set_index on is the new `index.dtype`. Unfortunately, in the following example, set_index changes the `dtype`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series(np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2], dtype=np.int8))})
df['ignore'] = df['a']
assert (df.dtypes == np.int8).all() # fine
df2=  df.set_index('a')
assert df2.index.dtype == df['a'].dtype, df2.index.dtype
```

Is it possible to avoid this behavior? My pandas version is 0.23.3

Similarly,

```
new_idx = pd.Index(np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2]), dtype=np.dtype('int8'))
assert new_idx.dtype == np.dtype('int64')
```

Even though the documentation for the dtype parameter says:     "If an actual dtype is provided, we coerce to that dtype if it's safe.
    Otherwise, an error will be raised."

Comment: I don't think you can. The index is up casted to int64 by default. Why is this an issue?

Comment: You need to `df2.index=df2.index.astype('int8')`

Comment: I want to use less memory

Comment: @Wen I don't think so. It is upcasted to int64 anyway.

Comment: @SamShleifer if memory is an issue then you must have many rows?  If so, np.int8 won't cut it for you.  Unless, you have many columns.  And if so, you can better solve your problem by messing with column dtypes.  Or maybe, you're working on a raspberrypi with dataframes of length less than 128, then I say goodluck to you and maybe you should create a custom class.  `np.iinfo(np.int8)` returns `iinfo(min=-128, max=127, dtype=int8)`

Answer (score 1):

Despite my bloviating in the comments above, this might suffice to get an appropriate index that is both low memory and starts from `-1`.

#### `pandas.RangeIndex`

Takes a start and stop parameters like `range`

```
df = df.set_index(pd.RangeIndex(-1, len(df) - 1))

print(df.index, df.index.dtype, sep='\n')
```

This should be very memory efficient.

Despite it still being of `dtype` `int64` (which you should want), it takes up very little memory.

```
pd.RangeIndex(-1, 4000000).memory_usage()

84
```

And

```
for i in range(1, 1000000, 100000):
  print(pd.RangeIndex(-1, i).memory_usage())

84
84
84
84
84
84
84
84
84
84
```